# How can I allow access to a single single resource/url via Nginx.conf?

Tags: symfony, nginx

I have an api based symfony project with nginx. I want to allow to some specific IP address to access a url. Below is the config i have done. But it's not working. I request it from my own machine using postman gives 512 Pre-condition failed.

```
location /requests/users {
    if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:80;

        allow   my_public_ip;
    }
    else{
        return 405;
    }    
}
```

Comment: and what is the url that is used in postman to send request?

Comment: server_ip+ /requests/users.

Comment: and why do you proxy this request to same server and same location `proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:80;`?

Comment: bcz this is api-gateway-nginx.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is you could possibly use Symfony to get the client IP and control the access based on client IP.

```
    $allowedIP = []; // allowed IP List

    $clientIP = $this->container->get('request')->getClientIp();

    if(!in_array($clientIP,$allowedIP)){
         throw new AccessDeniedHttpException(sprintf('You are not granted access to this API'));
    }
```

Comment: No I don't want this. I want to allow this from web-server end.

Comment: remove single quote `$request_method = GET`